# Listbox in CustomMessageBox always scrolls up

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, listbox, messagebox

I've got a weird problem with a listbox, which is placed in a custommessagebox.

Problem: You can't scroll down the list, because a "draggesture" up does the same thing than down. So the only thing I got is the respond-animation when your at the top of the list.

I made a little sample:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <Button Background="Bisque" Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"></Button>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = new string[200];

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            source[i] = i.ToString();
        }

        var dialog = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            Content = new ListBox(){ItemsSource = source},
            RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
            LeftButtonContent = "Store",
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
            HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        };

        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

And here is the link, if you wanna download it:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6B27FD720F1FB58D!15988&authkey=!ACG5krcfzsoBxA8&ithint=folder%2csln

Does anyone has an idea whats going wrong?
Thx for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple fix for that.. Add a `Height` to the `ListBox`. Like this.

```
var dialog = new CustomMessageBox()
{
    Content = new ListBox(){ItemsSource = source, Height = 800},
    RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
    LeftButtonContent = "Store",
    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, // Change to Top
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, // Change to Top
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
};
```

Change the `VerticalContentAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to Top so when you set the Height value less than 800 the content is aligned to the top.

Comment: Giving just a fix height solved the problem. It is not necessary to change VerticalAlignment to Top. But better is to set the MaxHeight instead of the Height. So you don't loose the adaptiv design. Thx a lot, never thought this would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just you need to add height for listbox as :

`Content = new ListBox(){ItemsSource = source,Height=800}`

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend setting the height, as Daniel Z mentioned you'll lose adaptive design. I managed a better workaround and it worked perfectly for me without setting the height to a static value.

Put the content of the `CustomMessageBox` in a `UserControl`. Suppose the `xaml` content of this control looks like this

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
        <!-- your listbox and content here -->
</Grid>
```

in the code behind, implement the `loaded` event:

```
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += UserControl1_Loaded;
}

void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LayoutRoot.Height = (this.Parent as CustomMessageBox).ActualHeight;
}
```

By setting the height of the grid, your listbox will automatically adjust its height to fit in. Hope it helps.